# Measure distance of line drawn on iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing

I am trying to creating an application that allows the user to draw a line on the screen and it measures the distance of the drawn line. I have been able to successfully draw the line but I don't know how to measure it. The line does not have to be perfectly straight either. It is basically a squiggle. If someone could please point me in the right direction or help guide me that would be awesome. I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and objective-c. I only just started dabbling in the language this summer.

EDIT: I am looking to measure the distance in either inches or cm. I would like the measurement to be the entire line, to follow the curve of the line. The distance not the displacement.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwipe = YES; //swipe declared in header

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view]; //tracking finger movement on screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 568)); // 568 iphone 5, 480 is iphone 4 (320,525)
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)]; // 0,0 centered in corner
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //round line end
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0); // width of line

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]); //sets color to red (change red to any color for that color)

    //CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,1,0,1); //green color
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); //start of when drawn path
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)]; //(320, 568)
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); //importnant
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); //finished drawing for time period
    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    [self.view addSubview:drawImage]; //adds to page
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; //touch fires of touch

    location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    lastClick = [NSDate date];

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view]; //stops connecting to previous line
    lastPoint.y -= 0;

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by distance - cm/inches measurement of the line on the physical screen, or distance in points/pixels, etc. And also, do you want the length measured to be the straight line length between start and end points, or do you want to measure it along the curves of the line?

Comment: To clarify @esker's question, what quantity are you interested in - the straight-line distance between the line's end points, or the length of the line (the distance you would walk if you walked along the line as drawn).  It's safe to assume both answers are desired in the coordinate system of the inputs (probably pixels).

Comment: I am looking to measure the distance in either inches or cm. I would like the measurement to be the entire line. The distance not the displacement.

Comment: Ok.  ('length' is a better term than 'distance' for this question).  Are you drawing it as the result of touchesMoved?  Then you'll be drawing from the last position to the current position.  Compute the cartesian distance between the successive points and cumulate them.

Comment: I am using touchesMoved. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please post that code.

Comment: @bolencki13 can u share the working code in gist.. I have similar requirement.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a property that cumulates the length of the path.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat pathLength;
```

Initialize it to `0.0` when user begins drawing the path.  Maybe do this in touchesBegan, or the same place elsewhere in your code where you realize you're beginning to draw.  Add a method that computes the cartesian distance between points:

```
- (CGFloat)distanceFrom:(CGPoint)p1 to:(CGPoint)p2 {
    CGFloat x = (p2.x - p1.x);
    CGFloat y = (p2.y - p1.y);
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}
```

As you get touches moved, you are already handling the current and last touch positions.  All you must do now is cumulate the distance between successive points:

```
// in touches moved, after you have lastPoint and currentPoint
self.pathLength += [self distanceFrom:currentPoint to:lastPoint];
```

There are quite a few refs here and elsewhere for converting these points to inches or cm.  As far as I can see all are fraught with the inability to get the device resolution  at runtime from the SDK.  If you're willing to add a (dangerous) constant to the code, you can [get PPI here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple), and divide that into the pathLength computed above.

Comment: I implemented what you had written and had it output to both a label and the debug log (NSLog). It is staying at 0.0. I'm not sure how to update it.

Comment: Can you NSLog(@"%f,%f", x,y); in that distanceFrom method?

Comment: The points are equal. input points:  263.500000(p2.y),263.500000(p1.y),89.000000(p2.x),89.000000(p1.x)

Comment: @bolencki13 if the points are equal, then the distance is zero

Comment: Yes i realize that but i don't know the correct formula to calculate the length of the line @Milo

Comment: @bolencki13 the method I suggest will correctly calculate distance, but the distance between the two equal points is zero.  Are you calling this before you set currentPoint equal to lastPoint?  The idea is to add up all those little linear distances between successive touch movements.  But most of those should be differing points from move to move.

Comment: Changed the location to where you suggested and it worked. Thank you very much